# Live code editor in the browser for three.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, three.js

In this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ENVYLp_NgY&feature=youtu.be&t=532 ,

He has opened code which he wrote **in the same window.**

Do you know the **name** of the plugin/extension, or is it a webgl/css3d "hack"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, its mr. doobs live coding editor from the video:

http://mrdoob.com/projects/htmleditor/